# Index out of bound exception while iterating over elements with same name in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am automating a mobile application through appium integrated with selenium web driver+testng. Now the problem i am facing is that i have list of tasks against which each task i have a link with same name (i.e: VIEW), same class name (i.e android.widget.TextView). Now i want to click on this specific 'VIEW' link for  which i am passing the task name. I am using the following code but it is giving java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 3 error.

```
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@enabled='true']")); //returing all the tasks 
        for(int i = 0 ; i< list.size() ; i++){

        String message1 = list.get(i).getText();
        //System.out.println(message1);
        if(message1.contains(ac+"-"+cnic)){
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='VIEW']")).get(i).click();
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looping on 'all the tasks', and then use that indice to get an element in a different list, the list of tasks with name 'VIEW'.
You should loop directly on the tasks with the name view, if I understood correctly. 
Also, you can use a foreach loop like Shubham said, or in java 8 a stream with a foreach().

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach loop instead of regular loop

```
 for (WebElement element : list ) {
        String message1 = element.getText();
        //System.out.println(message1);
        if(message1.contains(ac+"-"+cnic)){
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        element.click();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response....Now it is clicking on the very first task in the list.  I want to click on that specific task whose text i am matching through ac and cnic.

Comment: I guess we have missed one closing tag } in code in if condition .. updated code .. copy and try again'

Comment: i have added that tag. I think you are not getting my point. The task name and View link both have different Xpaths. The code you shared is clicking on the specific task name (that i am matching through ac +cnic) and it is not clicking on VIEW link that is displaying in front of each task.